# How to Remove newline characters from List<String>

Tags: java, regex, xml, data-structures, stax

I've got method which returns me a Map from an XML file. I've converted that map to separate Keys and Values into List.

However I'm noticing there are newline characters in the values list. How can I strip out the newline and replace them with a space or leave them blank.

Code:

```
@Test
public void testGetXMLModelData() throws Exception {
    File f = new File("xmlDir/example.xml");
    Model m = getXMLModelData(f);

    logger.debug("Models Keys: "+m.getInputs());
    logger.debug("Models Values: "+m.getValues());
}

public Model getXMLModelData(File f) throws Exception { 

    Model model = new Model();

    Map<String,String> map = p(f);
    List<String> listKeys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    List<String> listValues = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());

    model.setInputs(listKeys);
    model.setValues(listValues); 

    return model;
}


public Map<String, String> p(File file) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

    while(xr.hasNext()) {

        int e = xr.next();
        if (e == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
            String name = xr.getLocalName();
            xr.next();
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = xr.getText();
            } catch (IllegalStateException exep) {
                exep.printStackTrace();
            }
            map.put(name, value);
        } 
    }
    return map;
}
```

Output:

```
2015-08-19 20:13:52,327 : Models Keys: [IRS1095A, MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP, WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt, MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP, MonthCdPP, ReturnData, IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd, PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP, MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP, IRS1040, ResidentStateInfoPP, SelfSelectPINGrp, MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP, Filer, ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP, PrimaryBirthDt, Return, ReturnHeader, TotalExemptionsCnt, AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt, PrimarySSN]
2015-08-19 20:13:52,328 : Models Values: [
      , 136, 22000, 125, SEPTEMBER, 
    , 1, 
        , 
        , 
      , 
          , 
      , 250, 
      , CA, 1970-01-01, 
  , 
    , 1, 22000, 555-11-2222]
```

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit:

XML file

```
<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile">
  <ReturnData>
    <IRS1095A uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
      <MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP uuid="69dc9dd5-5415-4ee4-a199-19b2dbb701be">
        <MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>136</MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP>
        <MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>125</MonthlyAdvancedPTCAmtPP>
        <MonthCdPP>SEPTEMBER</MonthCdPP>
        <MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>250</MonthlyPremiumSLCSPAmtPP>
      </MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP>
    </IRS1095A>
    <IRS1040>
      <IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd>1</IndividualReturnFilingStatusCd>
      <WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt>22000</WagesSalariesAndTipsAmt>
      <TotalExemptionsCnt>1</TotalExemptionsCnt>
      <AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt>22000</AdjustedGrossIncomeAmt>
    </IRS1040>
  </ReturnData>
  <ReturnHeader>
    <SelfSelectPINGrp>
      <PrimaryBirthDt>1970-01-01</PrimaryBirthDt>
    </SelfSelectPINGrp>
    <Filer>
      <PrimarySSN>555-11-2222</PrimarySSN>
      <PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP>
        <ResidentStateInfoPP uuid="a77f40a2-af31-4404-a27d-4c1eaad730c2">
          <ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP>CA</ResidentStateAbbreviationCdPP>
        </ResidentStateInfoPP>
      </PrimaryResidentStatesInfoGrpPP>
    </Filer>
  </ReturnHeader>
</Return>
```

Comment: Show the XML file too.

Comment: I've posted the XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `value = xr.getText().trim()`.  That will trim extraneous characters from the beginning and end of the values.

To then prevent adding the value, wrap the `map.put(name, value)` with an `if (value != null && !value.isEmpty())`

Comment: How could I get just the values and no empty values, looks like the parsing I'm doing is getting every node even root nodes with no values.

Comment: Wrap your map.put() command in an if statement where you check for an non-empty value.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: That would be very helpful, I look forward to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't technically part of the answer, so I'll put it here, but you should move everything related to the value into the try block.  You can combine the value declaration and the assignment into one step and remove the null check from my answer addendum.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is extracting the element name and the text immediately following the start element, ignoring any text following an end element.

So, it collects:

```
Return = <newline><space><space>
ReturnData = <newline><space><space><space><space>
IRS1095A = <newline><space><space><space><space><space><space>
MonthlyPTCInformationGrpPP = <newline><space><space><space><space><space><space><space><space>
MonthlyPlanPremiumAmtPP = 136
...
```

And then you add those to a HashMap, which shuffles the key/value pairs in random order, making it difficult to see what happened.

**Updated**

I'm not going to write the code for you, but if you want "value elements" then you need to:

1. Remember start element when seen
2. Collect any text, concatenating with other text already collected, e.g. when you see <text><cdata><text>
3. When seeing a start element and a start element is remembered, verify text is empty or all whitespace, then discard text
4. When seeing an end element:

   1. if start element is remembered, add elementName/text to result, then forget start element and discard text. Note: Don't use map if same element name can occur more than once.
   2. if start element is not remembered (was forgotton), verify text is empty or all whitespace, then discard text

This will collect just the leaf elements, ignoring any "layout".

**Code *exactly* as written above**

Well, I did add missing resource cleanup.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);
    try (
        String elementName = null;
        StringBuilder textBuf = new StringBuilder();
        while (xr.hasNext()) {
            switch (xr.next()) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                    // 3. When seeing a start element and a start element is remembered
                    if (elementName != null) {
                        // verify text is empty or all whitespace
                        if (! textBuf.toString().trim().isEmpty())
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found text mixed with elements");
                        // then discard text
                        textBuf.setLength(0);
                    }
                    // 1. Remember start element when seen
                    elementName = xr.getLocalName();
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                case XMLStreamConstants.CDATA:
                case XMLStreamConstants.SPACE:
                    // 2. Collect any text
                    textBuf.append(xr.getText());
                    break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT: // 4. When seeing an end element
                    if (elementName != null) { // 1. if start element is remembered
                        // add elementName/text to result
                        map.put(elementName, textBuf.toString());
                        // then forget start element
                        elementName = null;
                        // and discard text
                        textBuf.setLength(0);
                    } else { // 2. if start element is not remembered (was forgotton)
                        // verify text is empty or all whitespace
                        if (! textBuf.toString().trim().isEmpty())
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found text mixed with elements");
                        // then discard text
                        textBuf.setLength(0);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    // ignore
            } 
        }
    } finally {
        xr.close();
    }
}
return map;
```

Comment: Yes you are exactly correct. I wasn't sure how to say this but you said it. How could I modify it to just collect the elements with values? I've been trying this for about 2 days now...no luck...problem is I'm not sure how to ask the question, but you seem to understand very well

Comment: Elements with values? What if `PrimarySSN` was an empty string? Do you still want it? Do you know the XML to read, or should it handle **any** XML file?

Comment: Yes exactly! You are reading my mind!! It should handle any XML so the document structure is not known in advance!

Comment: I'm having some trouble following this, I'm a noob to all this. An example would be much appreciated.